# Node.js + MongoDB without MongoJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Question is as you might have guessed from title, if I can use Node.JS with connected to MongoDB, without loaded MongoJS module.

I want to minimize application on maximum, so loading external module will load client.
What are other alternatives to MongoJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly use the [mongodb-native](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native) driver without using the MongoJS module which wraps it.

```
npm install mongodb
```

See the docs [here](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/).

Comment: @Mpa4Hu MongoJS is easier to use, but directly using mongodb-native works fine as well.